# How to set value of height or width of cell precisely? - ms excel Office 365

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, office365, cells, microsoft-excel-365

I'm going to make labels for pasting in MS Excel Microsoft Business 365. I have version 1903 (compilation 11425.20228). But they should made precisely and perfectly.

1. Now when I begin editing the height of cell in MS Excel I set the value on `15,3`. Then I click `OK` the value is set on `15,5`.
2. When I set the value on `15,333` then is set on `15,25`.
3. When I write the value on `15,22222` is set on `15,25`.

The same applies with setting width of cell. I have no clue how to deal with or solve it.

Can someone suggest me that how to do it?

Comment: Excel is a spreadsheet application, it's not optimized for producing output to print, it might not be your tool to use for this job. I'd try to use e.g. Word or Publisher instead, if you already use MS Office, or any text editor / publishing tool.

Comment: @MátéJuhász so there is no solution to deal with? Maybe what about change the languages in ms Excel. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I don't see why changing language would affect cell dimensions, however it seems easy, so you can just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is not a precise desktop publishing tool. Units of measure for row height will be rounded up or down to the next possible measure.

You have more control if you set your unit of measure for the ruler with File > Options > Advanced > Display > Ruler Unit

Then go to View ribbon > Page Layout. Now you can define the height with the ruler unit you set in the advanced options. There will still be some adjustment up or down, but at least you have better control of the units used.